# email is not sent using SendGrid/cloud composer

Tags: google-cloud-platform, airflow, sendgrid, google-cloud-composer

I'm trying to send an email using **SenDGrid** but the DAG is stuck on running.
I did the following:

1. set the environment variable *SENDGRID_MAIL_FROM* as my email
2. set the environment variable *SENDGRID_API_KEY* as the api I've generated from Sendgrid after confirming my personal email (same as sender email).

No spam im my email inbox.
Nothing found in the Activity section on SendGrid page and nothing is sent.
Can someone maybe point out what am I doing wrong?

My code:

```
from airflow.models import (DAG, Variable)
import os

from airflow.operators.email import EmailOperator
from datetime import datetime,timedelta

default_args = {
    'start_date': datetime(2020, 1, 1),
    'owner': 'Airflow',
    "email_on_failure" : False,
    "email_on_retry" : False,
    "emails" : ['my@myemail.com']
}

PROJECT_ID = os.environ.get("GCP_PROJECT_ID", "bigquery_default")
PROJECT_ID_GCP = os.environ.get("GCP_PROJECT_ID", "my_progect")

with DAG(
        'retries_test',
        schedule_interval=None,
        catchup=False,
        default_args=default_args
) as dag:

    send_email_notification = EmailOperator(
        task_id = "send_email_notification",
        to = "test@sendgrid.com",
        subject = "test",
        html_content = "<h3>Hello</h3>"
    )

send_email_notification
```

Comment: Did you get any solution? I am facing the same issue.

Comment: Unfortunately, no.

Comment: Actually I got it working, but with PythonOperator and `from airflow.utils.email import send_email` method.